# nltk NERTagger UnicodeDecodeError in python

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am writing a program in python 2.7.6 that uses nltk with Stanford named entity tagger in Window 7 professional to tag a text and print the result as follows:

```
import re

from nltk.tag.stanford import NERTagger

WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')

st = NERTagger("./classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz", "stanford-ner.jar")

text = "title Wienfilm 1896-1976 (1976)"

words = WORD.findall(text )

print words

answer = st.tag(words )

print answer
```

The last print statement in the program suppose to return a tuple consisting of five lists as:

```
     [(u'title', u'O'), (u'Wienfilm', u'O'), (u'1896', u'O'), (u'1976', u'O'), (u'1976', u'O')]
```

However when I run the program, it gives me the following error message:

```
['title', 'Wienfilm', '1896', '1976', '1976']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Google Drive\myPyPrgs\testNLP.py", line 27, in <module>
    answer = st.tag(words )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 59, in tag
    return self.tag_sents([tokens])[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 82, in tag_sents
    stanpos_output = stanpos_output.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 23: ordinal not in  
  range(128)
```

Note that if I remove the number, '-1976' from the text string the program tags and prints the correct answer. But if the number '-1976' is within the text, I always have the above error.

In this forum, somebody suggested to me to change the default encoding in the stanford.py of the nltk. When I changed the default encoding in the stanford.py from ascii to UTF-16  and replaced the the last print statement of the above code with the following looping:

```
    for i, word_pos in enumerate(answer):
         word, pos = word_pos
         print i ,  word.encode('utf-16'), pos.encode('utf-16')
```

I got the following incorrect output:

```
             0 ÿþ ÿþtitle/O Wienfilm/O 1896 1976 1976/O
```

Please any clues on how to deal with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with `u"title Wienfilm 1896-1976 (1976)"`

Comment: Thank u for your quick respond. I did what you said but i still got the same error.

Comment: what about add `# -*- coding: utf-16 -*-`  on top level of your code ?

Comment: the byte `0xa0` just could be decode with `utf-16` encoding : `>>> print '0xa0'.decode('utf-16')
砰ち` so you need to change the encoding of  `stanford.py` .

Comment: You need to set the default encoding, as the issue lies in NLTK, not your input. (see my answer)

Comment: I did what you said. It said invalid syntax on line 1. That is the line a add {# -*- coding: utf-16 -*- }

Comment: you need to add all of `# -*- coding: utf-16 -*-`

Comment: Kasra/Peter how do  i change the encode in Stanfold.py please I am new in both python and nltk

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: specify the encoding argument as UTF-8 when you create NERTagger object

```
st = NERTagger("./classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz", "stanford-ner.jar", encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal(cmd), and write;

```
chcp
```

It should return something like;

> active code page: 857

Then, write;

```
chcp 1254
```

After then, in your .py script, to the top of your script write;

```
# -*- coding: cp1254 -*-
```

This should solve your problem.If it's not, copy these codes and paste to the top of your script.

```
# -*-coding:utf-8-*-
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

I had many problems with decoding before, these methods solved.

> [**ASCII**](http://www.asciitable.com/) can decode only 2^7 = 128  characters, that's why you getting that error.As you see in the error sentence *ordinal not in range(128)* .

And check [**this**](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#2) website please.Use arrow keys for switching pages :-) I believe it's going to solve your problem.

Comment: grrr: Thank you. I did as you said but i still have the error

Comment: Did you do last part too? Also Python 3x is really good at decoding my little advice is switch to Python 3.4

Comment: I did grrr the Error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your app add:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Comment: Peter. I have editted your suggestion. I dont know if you have seen it?

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same problem and I solved it by adding the encoding options on internals.py in nltk.

You must open internals.py saven on:
%YourPythonFolder%\Lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py

Then go to the method java and adding this line after #construct the full command string (about line 147)

```
cmd = cmd + ['-inputEncoding', 'utf-8', '-outputEncoding', 'utf-8']
```

This section code must look like:

```
# Construct the full command string.
cmd = list(cmd)
cmd = ['-cp', classpath] + cmd
cmd = [_java_bin] + _java_options + cmd
cmd = cmd + ['-inputEncoding', 'utf-8', '-outputEncoding', 'utf-8']
```

Hope it helps.